# How to create a 360 image with clickable (touch) points of interest with a-frame

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, aframe

I have a 360 image where you have to look around to find an element and click on it using your finger on a mobile device.
Is it possible to have a 360 image with clickable interests using A-frame?
I'm aware of this tutorial: https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/guides/building-a-360-image-gallery.html
But it's not exactly the desired effect.

- There should be no "cursor" in the center
- A point of interest should be clickable using your finger (or mouse on the computer) even if the point of interest is not in the middle of the screen.

This seems like a basic functionality, but I just can't seem to get this.
Thanks ahead!

I've done multiple tutorials, started from scratch, but I can't seem to get this to work exactly as described.

Comment: hi, did you have any luck?

Answer (score 0):

you can add a box or any shape to the scene and then attach a click event to it. don t forget to add this entity to your scene:

i beleive that s not the best sollution but it works
i think there is another way with hotspot entity you can serch for
it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).